# Re-allocate space from one Volume Group to another Volume Group - Linux CentOs

Tags: linux, centos7, filesystems, lvm

I have a dedicated server provided to me by 1and1. I started migrating websites to the server only to realise that I am running out of disk space. I had to clear my backups in order to continue migrating my sites. I thought this to be weird as the server comes with 4T of disk space.

On accessing the system via ssh. I see the following setup by 1and1:

```
#vgdisplay

 --- Volume group ---
VG Name               vg00
System ID
Format                lvm2
Metadata Areas        1
Metadata Sequence No  8
VG Access             read/write
VG Status             resizable
MAX LV                0
Cur LV                3
Open LV               3
Max PV                0
Cur PV                1
Act PV                1
VG Size               <54.00 GiB
PE Size               4.00 MiB
Total PE              13823
Alloc PE / Size       11520 / 45.00 GiB
Free  PE / Size       2303 / <9.00 GiB
VG UUID               CmLv2a-xKAn-cFQQ-K4TU-f5y2-UK8K-Uv1PO9

--- Volume group ---
VG Name               hdd
System ID
Format                lvm2
Metadata Areas        1
Metadata Sequence No  2
VG Access             read/write
VG Status             resizable
MAX LV                0
Cur LV                1
Open LV               1
Max PV                0
Cur PV                1
Act PV                1
VG Size               <3.58 TiB
PE Size               4.00 MiB
Total PE              938308
Alloc PE / Size       1024 / 4.00 GiB
Free  PE / Size       937284 / <3.58 TiB
VG UUID               Pv2xfH-zkE1-hgH0-dOzZ-FgKp-IobS-5C2zea

Also #pvscan reveals this:
PV /dev/sda3   VG vg00            lvm2 [<54.00 GiB / <9.00 GiB free]
PV /dev/sdb1   VG hdd             lvm2 [<3.58 TiB / <3.58 TiB free]
```

Can someone please let me know the best process for getting this unused free space in to the root volume group? I have searched and seen so many different answers. As I have already started migrating a number of websites. I cannot afford to break the server, otherwise I would have a fiddle, break, and learn as I usually do.

Just a thought failed to mention this is Hardware Raid 5

Update to question below:

```
#pvdisplay
--- Physical volume ---
 PV Name               /dev/sda3
 VG Name               vg00
 PV Size               <54.00 GiB / not usable 2.81 MiB
 Allocatable           yes
 PE Size               4.00 MiB
 Total PE              13823
 Free PE               767
 Allocated PE          13056
 PV UUID               6J06IE-52et-s8aV-bXk0-alud-0N1v-NEwHHr

 --- Physical volume ---
 PV Name               /dev/sdb1
 VG Name               hdd
 PV Size               <3.58 TiB / not usable <3.78 MiB
 Allocatable           yes
 PE Size               4.00 MiB
 Total PE              938308
 Free PE               937284
 Allocated PE          1024
 PV UUID               bGlBQQ-gnmF-gOav-VTfj-np5R-sAKs-YNxemq
```

I would like to reduce the physical volume in /dev/sdb1 by 2 or 3TB and increase /dev/sda3 by the same amount. Can this be done? If so what process would I need to follow?

If not I noticed mentioned in the replies "Migrating the websites to hdd" What process would I have to follow and what are the implications of doing this?

```
Logical Volumes: 

--- Logical volume ---
LV Path                /dev/vg00/usr
LV Name                usr
VG Name                vg00
LV UUID                sRvgQ3-W80K-AJQD-lZid-fqF3-1KTY-JH2Ul0
LV Write Access        read/write
LV Creation host, time ,
LV Status              available
# open                 1
LV Size                15.00 GiB
Current LE             3840
Segments               2
Allocation             inherit
Read ahead sectors     auto
- currently set to     8192
Block device           253:0

--- Logical volume ---
LV Path                /dev/vg00/var
LV Name                var
VG Name                vg00
LV UUID                xWSCRG-vBPH-JLha-yJ8X-3zMP-WgRG-AOoJqO
LV Write Access        read/write
LV Creation host, time ,
LV Status              available
# open                 1
LV Size                31.00 GiB
Current LE             7936
Segments               3
Allocation             inherit
Read ahead sectors     auto
- currently set to     8192
Block device           253:1

--- Logical volume ---
LV Path                /dev/vg00/home
LV Name                home
VG Name                vg00
LV UUID                2foQrE-Wy3C-Ig1Z-zIDy-tTFQ-YyO5-ayHBZl
LV Write Access        read/write
LV Creation host, time ,
LV Status              available
# open                 1
LV Size                5.00 GiB
Current LE             1280
Segments               1
Allocation             inherit
Read ahead sectors     auto
- currently set to     8192
Block device           253:2

--- Logical volume ---
LV Path                /dev/hdd/data
LV Name                data
VG Name                hdd
LV UUID                GwJgTL-LC8r-jn0a-yQ5H-mTX3-dARL-Xz0eOU
LV Write Access        read/write
LV Creation host, time ,
LV Status              available
# open                 1
LV Size                4.00 GiB
Current LE             1024
Segments               1
Allocation             inherit
Read ahead sectors     auto
- currently set to     8192
Block device           253:3
```

I increased the LV on /dev/vg00/var by 100% (This is where the websites are stored). but this will quickly be used up once I continue to migrate more sites over!

This may also help. This is from running the mount command I have removed additional lines:

```
/dev/sda1 on / type ext3 (rw,noatime,data=ordered)
/dev/mapper/vg00-usr on /usr type ext4 (rw,noatime,data=ordered)
/dev/mapper/hdd-data on /data type ext4 (rw,noatime,quota,usrquota,data=ordered)
/dev/mapper/vg00-home on /home type ext4 (rw,noatime,quota,usrquota,data=ordered)
/dev/mapper/vg00-var on /var type ext4 (rw,noatime,quota,usrquota,data=ordered)
```

Thank you for your responses much appreciated!

Comment: first you need to check if you have free space on you physical volume using pvdisplay

Comment: What LV's does exist? Do you need the one in VG `hdd`? Could you not simply migrate the websites to newly created LVs?

Comment: Is it possible that this is caused by very conservative allocation of the space to volumes? You are not providing any hints what filesystem is lacking space, on what logical volume it is located and on which volume group. Without this information we cannot judge if you really need to reallocate space between volume groups, it may be as easy as expanding logical volume and filesystem on it.

Comment: @c4f4t0r Hi guys, thank you for your response . I have updated the question. I think I have cover what you asked. Please let me know if this is enough information to advise me further.

Comment: @Tomek Hi guys, thank you for your response . I have updated the question. I think I have cover what you asked. Please let me know if this is enough information to advise me further

Comment: @Sven Hi guys, thank you for your response . I have updated the question. I think I have cover what you asked. Please let me know if this is enough information to advise me further

Answer (score 0):

I assume that /data is where the data you are migrating is going to be. The underlying volume is on 'hdd' volume group which is over 3.5 TB large. Why don't you set its size to something which is going to be enough for data you are migrating? You should be able to measure it on the source(s) and adjust /dev/hdd/data accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes it is the safest process that I was after!....I am just gonna go with using a symbolic link and moving my vhosts over to the /dev/hdd/data drive instead! Do you know of any negative implications with doing this?